# jpg, загруженный в unity3d на андроиде, показывается неверно

Tags: unity3d, jpeg

Есть приложение, пока все, что оно делает - это загружает фотографию. 
Делаю фотографию вертикально, кресло. В галерее она отображается правильно. 
В приложении - боком. Пробовалось на 4 разных девайсах, все самсунги. Один девайс вообще из коробки.
Версии андроида от 5 до 7. Пробовал просмотреть картинку на компе - XnView отображает ее правильно. 
А вот по ссылке тоже боком. http://pixs.ru/showimage/Armchairjp_1356002_29545584.jpg

Подозреваю, что дело в EXIF, который кто-то читает и преобразует правильно, а кто-то нет. Но как это пофиксить?

Answer (score 0):

> В приложении - боком. 
>   Вы имеете ввиду под 90 градусов?

Если да, то просто поверните объект на сцене (на который вы накладываете изображение)

Comment: Добрый день. Что можно сделать для исправления - это понятно. Непонятно, почему в Галерее картинка отображается правильно, а в приложении - да, повернуто на 90 градусов. Откуда берется этот эффект? Пользователь приложения должен видеть картинку так же, как она отображается в галерее.

Comment: Галерея может сама переворачивать вам для удобства, или при создании текстуры с изображения, она автоматически ставит её в одно положение (не смотря на то, в каком изображение)

Comment: Коллега, я понимаю, что вы в юнити разбираетесь лучше меня. Но вот логически мне не ясно. Как именно галерея может ставить фотографии в правильную позицию? Вертикальные фото отображаются вертикально. Горизонтальные - горизонтально. Фотографии не перевернуты вверх ногами и т.п. Если бы галерея их все преобразовывала - часть из них выглядела бы некорректно. Однако этого не происходит.

Comment: Попробуем с другой стороны, как вы думаете, при создании из фотографии - текстуры есть ли логика проверки, вертикальная ли фотография или горизонтальная?

Comment: думаю, есть. Если смотреть в EXIF, то верно отображающаяся фотография имеет ориентацию top-left(1), неверно right-top(6)

Comment: нет, текстуре все равно, положите вы туда 16:9 или 9:16, она создастся с одним углом

Comment: Хочу пояснить: это одна и та же фотография кресла.

В одном случае прямо с телефона, тогда в exif у нее right-top(6)  Отображается повернутой.  

Во-втором случае она пережата в XnView. В exif  top-left(1) и отображается нормально.